# Reading from xls file in PGSQL

Tags: excel, postgresql

I have code in mSSQL which reads from .xls file.

```
SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10 
    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
        'Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;Database=**Y:\2021.xlsx**', [Global$]);
```

Looking forward for a code in PGSQL to read from xls file as copy command reads from csv or text file.
Please help
Thanks

Comment: You won't find it. You will need to either export CSV from the XLS and then copy in or find some package that reads XLS and will output CSV in order to copy it in.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver:thanks !